# Latest omniauth-facebook gem breaks devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.1'

I'm using the latest omniauth-facebook and devise together
Gemfile:
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'

Getting this error when starting the server:

/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/lib/devise/omniauth.rb:12:in `': You are using an old OmniAuth version, please ensure you have 1.0.0.pr2 version or later installed. (RuntimeError)

The problem is that if I try to use older omniauth-facebook versions the server works but then the Facebook authentication stops working properly (e.g. fails including emails despite

scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email,name'

in devise.rb. )

I have tried many different version combinations of omniauth-facebook and devise. Either Facebook-authentication stops working properly or the server fails (see above).

Comment: This is a known issue with devise and there is a PR https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5327

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using

```
gem 'devise', github: 'heartcombo/devise', branch: 'ca-omniauth-2'
```

In Gemfile will fix the problem, awaiting a merge.

Updated my answer based on Carlos answer below, I was in a rush when I posted this using ref.

Thank You, Carlos for maintaining Devise.

Comment: More information can be found here https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5327

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solves the problem of the server not starting. However, it is now running into that seemingly unsolvable "Not found. Authentication passthru." problem, which - for the same code - didn't happen with the older facebook-omniauth versions. (Already tried all existing stackoverflow suggestions for that.) In any case, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @jco40 did you figure out, ""Not found. Authentication passthru."
I have started getting the same.

Comment: Change your links to 

user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post 

and add the Gem https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection



For more information visit:https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5236

Answer (score 11):

This is Carlos, Devise maintainer. Please keep an eye on that Pull Request linked above, I just [shared how you can test it in your app there](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5327#issuecomment-763798550):

I'd recommend using the branch ref instead of the git ref directly:

```rb
gem 'devise', github: 'heartcombo/devise', branch: 'ca-omniauth-2'
```

With that you should be able to run `bundle update devise omniauth` which should hopefully give you OmniAuth 2 and this Devise branch. That should allow the app to boot up.

Lastly, if you've copied over the Devise shared links on your app, or if you have your own links to initiate the OmniAuth authentication flow, you need to make sure they're changed to use a form. (you can do that by using link_to with `method: :post` option for example, or using `button_to`, if that works for your app.) Please note that this is a requirement change in how OmniAuth work due to a security issue, [read more](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

If you run into any issues please comment back in GitHub, and we'll work to get them resolved soon so we can release a new Devise version that fully supports OmniAuth 2. Thanks.

Comment: Update as on Apr 17, 2021: It seems the above branch is now merged to master. So just `gem 'devise', github: 'heartcombo/devise'` works (get the gem from master).

Answer (score 10):

Devise 4.8.0 (shipped yesterday) resolves this.

Comment: This one is the answer for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please downgrade OmniAuth:

```
gem "omniauth", "~> 1.9.1"
```

That's worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if this advise is good. Omniauth < 2.0.0 has a vulnerability marked with criticality high.
Bundler audit sais to upgrade to omniauth >= 2.0.0

https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Resolving-CVE-2015-9284

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the issue is related to this devise PR, https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/pull/5327

Devise currently has a version check that doesn't include OmaniAuth > 1.x.x

Comment: Thanks! Make sense. I guess we have to wait for the devise gem update then. In the meantime are you aware of any Omniauth-facebook version that hits the sweet spot i.e. new enough to include Facebook emails, old enough to work with devise?