# Rails server stopped running after omniauth update (breaks devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I followed the pull request from the branch to the master (devise) but I'm still having the error and I can't deploy the api to the server anymore

I also tried the solutions provided in this question but  was not successful:

[Latest omniauth-facebook gem breaks devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65702896/latest-omniauth-facebook-gem-breaks-devise/66011361#66011361)

The error:

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/lib/devise/omniauth.rb:12:in `<top (required)>': You are using an old OmniAuth version, please ensure you have 1.0.0.pr2 version or later installed. (RuntimeError)
```

the error is the same on localhost

Ruby version: 2.5.1p57

rails (5.1.7)

devise (4.7.3)

omniauth (2.0.1)

omniauth-facebook (8.0.0)

omniauth-oauth2 (1.7.1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [this commit](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/commit/1d138dd40cdc291a427b89027d16a869818a5c19#diff-59866e40fe6196ebb76fa63d186b09ba0856de17e2e938743e99add37bb83f5c) fixes the issue you are seeing, unfortunately it will not automatically be pulled into your project through `bundle update` until devise bumps their version.

So I think you can fix this in the Gemfile with `gem 'devise', github: 'heartcombo/devise'` (you may need to uninstall the original version first)

And you can verify by using `bundle show devise` to reveal where the new gem is, go to lib/devise/omniauth.rb, and make sure it opens with the following:

```
# PATH_TO_DEVISE_GEM/lib/devise/omniauth.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

begin
  gem "omniauth", ">= 1.0.0"

  require "omniauth"
rescue LoadError
  warn "Could not load 'omniauth'. Please ensure you have the omniauth gem >= 1.0.0 installed and listed in your Gemfile."
  raise
end
```

What my version had when I ran into this exact same problem yesterday was the following, and this is why it was breaking it for me:

```
# PATH_TO_OLD_DEVISE_GEM/lib/devise/omniauth.rb

[...]
unless OmniAuth::VERSION =~ /^1\./  if Gem::Version.new(OmniAuth::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('1.0.0')
  raise "You are using an old OmniAuth version, please ensure you have 1.0.0.pr2 version or later installed."     raise "You are using an old OmniAuth version, please ensure you have 1.0.0 version or later installed."
end
[...]
```

Comment: Works at my localhost, but when i deploy with dokku falls in the same error, i don't know how i can force rebundle the gem in the container

Answer (score 4):

Updating *devise* to the latest version (currently 4.8.0) should solve the issue. I can confirm that it did so in my case.

More info here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/commit/1d138dd40cdc291a427b89027d16a869818a5c19#commitcomment-50168476.